# How can I pass arguments from view to cportlet in Yii?

Tags: view, yii, arguments

I want to pass some arguments from a view to the cportlet widgets called by this view, but it seems doesn't work when I do it like this:

```
<?php
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet');
        $this->widget('ProductsBrowser',
            array('params'=>$params));
        $this->endWidget();  ?>
```

How can I accomplish it succesfully? Please help me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Do You read documentation?
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.use#widget this just should work.

Answer (score 0):

The Correct way is as shown

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet', array(
    'params'=>$params)); ?>

//body content 

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```